# Woocommerce - How to display content after product summary but before the description?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to display some content on my single product page below the product summary and above the tabs with the review

I use [this](https://storecustomizer.com/woocommerce-product-page-hooks-visual-guide/) guide as a reference for the hooks, so I thought `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` would be the right one. But alas, it displays my content right at the bottom of the product page.

The full code I use is:

```
function product_summary() {
    echo '<h2>Test!</h2>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'product_summary', 11);
```

All the other hooks I tried work perfectly so I don't get why this one doesn't. I do use the plugin 'custom tabs' so that might interfere (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd party plugin might interfere default order of course, but in your case it seems the problem is priority.

By default woocommerce_after_single_product_summary action has 3 hooks:

- woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
- woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
- woocommerce_output_related_products - 20

So in order to get printed before these 3 ones, you need to use smaller priority. F.e. 0 or 1 or 2 or 9.  But not 11.

If even that one doesn't work, you will need to debug the code and print all default+custom hooks of woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.

To see which hooks the given action has, you can use this code (at footer area of your template f.e.):

```
 global $wp_filter;
 var_dump($wp_filter["woocommerce_after_single_product_summary"]);
```